Solution to NDSolve changes when variable range changes?
I am trying to use NDSolve to find a solution to a differential equation for $u[t]$ that should asymptote to a particular value $u_0$ as $t$ goes to negative infinity. This is a very unstable solution but I'm trying to find it by keeping $u[0]$ fixed and adjusting $u'[0]$ by hand as in the "shooting method." If I adjust $u'[0]$ a little too low the solution goes to negative infinity and if I adjust $u'[0]$ a little too high it goes to positive infinity, but the hope is that if I tune it just right the solution will sit near $u_0$ (at least for a while).
But I am encountering some kind of numerical problem even before I get close to $u_0$. If I simply adjust the range over which the equation is solved the nature of the solution I get from NDSolve changes. No error message to indicate that the solution might be untrustworthy shows up.

In the plot above, the blue curve and orange curve are solutions with the same initial conditions at $t=0$ but the blue curve was solved from {t,-2.5,0} and the orange curve was solved from {t,-2.6,0}. Both are plotted here on the range {t,-2.5,0} together with the green line, which is the value of $u_0$ I want to eventually reach.
What is going wrong with NDSolve, and how do I change the settings so that the solution is consistent and trustworthy? My code is below:
Solving with a lower bound at -2.5

solve1 = NDSolve[{((56 E^(12 t) + 78 E^(14 t) + 30 E^(16 t)) u[
         t] + (E^(6 t) + E^(8 t)) (15 E^(6 t) + 11 E^(8 t)) Derivative[1][u][
         t])/(E^(6 t) + E^(8 t))^2 + (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == (
     100 E^(-10 t) ((8 E^(15 t) + 6 E^(17 t)) u[t] + 
        E^(14 t) u[t]^2 + (E^(15 t) + E^(17 t)) Derivative[1][u][t])^2)/(E^(
       6 t) + E^(8 t))^3, u[0] == 0.0166, u'[0] == -.016484835}, 
   u, {t, -2.5, 0}];

Solving with a lower bound at -2.6

solve2 = NDSolve[{((56 E^(12 t) + 78 E^(14 t) + 30 E^(16 t)) u[
         t] + (E^(6 t) + E^(8 t)) (15 E^(6 t) + 11 E^(8 t)) Derivative[1][u][
         t])/(E^(6 t) + E^(8 t))^2 + (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == (
     100 E^(-10 t) ((8 E^(15 t) + 6 E^(17 t)) u[t] + 
        E^(14 t) u[t]^2 + (E^(15 t) + E^(17 t)) Derivative[1][u][t])^2)/(E^(
       6 t) + E^(8 t))^3, u[0] == 0.0166, u'[0] == -.016484835}, 
   u, {t, -2.6, 0}];

Showing both solutions, together with asymptotic value I am trying to reach


Plot[{Evaluate[u[t] /. solve1], Evaluate[u[t] /. solve2], (8*7/100)^(
  1/3)}, {t, -2.5, 0}, PlotRange -> All]


Your code generates errors ("The function u appears with no arguments") (v13.3)

Fixing the problem noted in my other comment, and adding option MaxStepFraction -> 0.001, yields the same curve for both.
